# How to copy part of a model onto another model

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

[image]

I want to take the 2 existing arms on this model(above)
and add another 2 below.

I have tried this in edit mode by duplicating polys but when I do that it only exists in edit mode and disappears when I leave edit mode.

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: hello maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/